# Fitting data with function with several domains whose boundaries are variable

Tags: python, curve-fitting, data-fitting, model-fitting

As the title mentions, I am having trouble fitting data points to a function with 3 domains whose boundaries are a parameter of my function. Here is the function I am dealing with:

```
global sigma_m
sigma_m=2*10**(-12)

global sigma_f
sigma_f=10**3

def Conductivity (phi,phi_c,t,s):
    sigma=[0]*(len(phi))
    for i in range (0,len(phi)):
        if phi[i]<phi_c:
            sigma[i]=sigma_m*(phi_c-phi[i])**(-s)
        elif phi[i]==phi_c:
            sigma[i]=sigma_f*(sigma_m/sigma_f)**(t/(t+s))
        else:
            sigma[i]=sigma_f*(phi[i]-phi_c)**t      
    return sigma
```

And my data points are:

```
phi_data=[0,0.005,0.007,0.008,0.017,0.05,0.085,0.10]
sigma_data=[2.00E-12,2.50E-12,3.00E-12,9.00E-04,1.00E-01,1.00E+00,2.00E+00,3.00E+00]
```

My constraints are that phi_c, s, and t must be strictly greater than zero (in practice, phi_c is rarely higher than 0.1 but higher than 0.001, s is usually between 0.5 and 1.5, and t is usually anywhere between 1.5 and 6).

My goal is to fit my data points and have my fit give me values of phi_c, s, and t. s and t can be estimated to help the code (in the specific set of data points that I showed, t should be around 2, and s should be around 0.5). phi_c is completely unknown, except for the range of values that I mentioned just above.

I have used both curve_fit from scipy and Model from lmfit but both provide ridiculously small phi_c values (like 10**(-16) or similarly small values that make me believe the programme wants phi_c to be negative).

Here is my code for when I used curve_fit:

```
popt, pcov = curve_fit(Conductivity, phi_data, sigma_data, p0=[0.01,2,0.5], bounds=(0,[0.5,10,3]))
```

Here is my code for when I used Model from lmfit:

```
t_estimate=0.5
s_estimate=2
phi_c_estimate=0.005
condmodel = Model(Conductivity)
params = condmodel.make_params(phi_c=phi_c_estimate,t=t_estimate,s=s_estimate)
result = condmodel.fit(sigma_data, params, phi=phi_data)
params['phi_c'].min = 0
params['phi_c'].max = 0.1
```

Both options give an okay fit when plotted, but the estimated value of phi_c is nowhere near plausible.
If you have any idea what I could do to have a better fit, please let me know!

PS: I have a read a promising post about using the package symfit to fit the data on the different regions separately, unfortunately the package symfit does not work for me. It keeps uninstalling my version of scipy then reinstalling an older version, and then it tells me it needs a newer version of scipy to function.

EDIT: I managed to make the symfit package work. Here is my entire code:

```
from symfit import parameters, variables, Fit, Piecewise, exp, Eq
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

global sigma_m
sigma_m=2*10**(-12)

global sigma_f
sigma_f=10**3

phi, sigma = variables ('phi, sigma')
t, s, phi_c = parameters('t, s, phi_c')

phi_c.min = 0.001
phi_c.max = 0.1

sigma1 = sigma_m*(phi_c-phi)**(-s)
sigma2 = sigma_f*(phi-phi_c)**t
model = {sigma: Piecewise ((sigma1, phi <= phi_c), (sigma2, phi > phi_c))}

constraints = [Eq(sigma1.subs({phi: phi_c}), sigma2.subs({phi: phi_c}))]

phi_data=np.array([0,0.005,0.007,0.008,0.017,0.05,0.085,0.10])
sigma_data=np.array([2.00E-12,2.50E-12,3.00E-12,9.00E-04,1.00E-01,1.00E+00,2.00E+00,3.00E+00])

fit = Fit(model, phi=phi_data, sigma=sigma_data, constraints=constraints)
fit_result = fit.execute()
print(fit_result)
```

Unfortunately I get the following error:

```
  File "D:\Programs\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sympy\printing\pycode.py", line 236, in _print_ComplexInfinity
    return self._print_NaN(expr)

  File "D:\Programs\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sympy\printing\pycode.py", line 74, in _print_known_const
    known = self.known_constants[expr.__class__.__name__]

KeyError: 'ComplexInfinity'
```

My knowledge of coding is very limited, I have no idea what this means and what I should do to not have this error anymore. Please let me know if you have an idea.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not certain that I have a single answer for you, but this will be too long to fit into a comment.

First, a model that switches functional form is especially challenging.  But, what's more is that your form has

```
 elif phi[i]==phi_c:
```

For floating point numbers that are variables, this is going to basically never be true.  You might not mean "exactly equal" but "pretty close", which might be

```
 elif abs(phi[i] - phi_c) < 1.0e-5:
```

or something...

But also, converting that from a for loop to using `numpy.where()` is probably worth looking into.

Second, it is not at all clear that your different forms actually evaluate to the same values at the boundaries to ensure a continuous function.  You might want to check that.

Third, models with powers and exponentials are especially challenging to fit as a small change in power can have a huge impact on the resulting value.  It's also very easy to get "negative value raised to non-integer value", which is of course, complex.

Fourth, those `sigma_m` and `sigma_f` constants look like they could easily cause trouble.  You should definitely evaluate your model with your starting parameter values and see if you can sort of reproduce your data with your model and reasonable starting values.  I suspect that you'll need to change your starting values.